# Difficulty rewriting code from c# to f# related to Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, f#, c#-to-f#

I have a block of code that I want to write in F#, but the examples I have are in C#. I would like some help to write this in the F# language, and help understanding how it works.

Here is the c# code I have to mimic:

```
builder.HasMany(r => r.Options).WithOne(o => o.Root).HasForeignKey(o => o.RootId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

In F#, I am trying to do this:

```
builder
    .HasOne(fun i -> i.ProductionReport) 
    .WithMany(fun pr -> pr.CostItems)
    .HasForeignKey(fun pr -> pr.ProductionReportId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade) |> ignore
```

And the issue, per visual studio, is that pr is of type obj. How do I make sure f# knows that pr is of type ProductionReport, according to the return type of builder.HasOne.

Here is the complete sample requested:

**BackendDemoDbContext**

```
namespace BackendDemo.BackendDemoContext

open Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

type BackendDemoContext(options: DbContextOptions<BackendDemoContext>) =
    inherit DbContext(options)


    override __.OnModelCreating modelbuilder =         
        //Todo:
        //modelbuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CostItemEntityTypeConfiguration());        
        //modelbuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductionReportEntityTypeConfiguration());
```

**CostItem**

```
namespace BackendDemo.Data.Models

type CostItem() = 
    member val CostItemId = null with get, set
    member val Paper1 = null with get, set    
    member val Paper2 = null with get, set
    member val Cases = null with get, set
    member val Boxes = null with get, set
    member val Paste = null with get, set
    member val Bundling = null with get, set
    member val Ink = null with get, set
    member val Cardboard = null with get, set
    member val Wrapping = null with get, set
    member val Labour = null with get, set
    member val Fringe = null with get, set
    member val Pallet = null with get, set

    member val ProductionReportId =null with get,set
    member val ProductionReport = null with get, set
```

**ProductionReport**

```
namespace BackendDemo.Data.Models

open System.Collections
open BackendDemo.Data.Models

type ProductionReport() = 
    //val keyword necessary for AutoProperties
    member val ProductionReportId : int = 2
    //Todo:
    //abstract member CostItems : ICollection<CostItem> with get, set
```

**CostItemEntityTypeConfiguration**

```
namespace BackendDemo.Data.EntityConfigurations

open Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
open Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders
open BackendDemo.Data.Models

type CostItemEntityTypeConfiguration =
    interface IEntityTypeConfiguration<CostItem> with

        override this.Configure(builder: EntityTypeBuilder<CostItem>) =
            builder.ToTable("CostItem") |> ignore
            builder.HasKey(fun i -> i.CostItemId) |> ignore
            builder.Property(fun i -> i.Paper1).IsRequired() |> ignore
            builder.Property(fun i -> i.Paper2).IsRequired() |> ignore
            builder.Property(fun i -> i.Cases).IsRequired() |> ignore
            builder.Property(fun i -> i.Boxes).IsRequired() |> ignore
            builder.Property(fun i -> i.Paste).IsRequired() |> ignore
            builder.Property(fun i -> i.Bundling).IsRequired() |> ignore
            builder.Property(fun i -> i.Ink).IsRequired() |> ignore
            builder.Property(fun i -> i.Cardboard).IsRequired() |> ignore
            builder.Property(fun i -> i.Wrapping).IsRequired() |> ignore
            builder.Property(fun i -> i.Labour).IsRequired() |> ignore
            builder.Property(fun i -> i.Fringe).IsRequired() |> ignore
            builder.Property(fun i -> i.Pallet).IsRequired() |> ignore

            builder
                .HasOne(fun i -> i.ProductionReport) 
                .WithMany(fun pr -> pr.CostItems)
                .HasForeignKey(fun pr -> pr.ProductionReportId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade) |> ignore
```

**ProductionReportEntityTypeConfiguration**

```
namespace BackendDemo.Data.EntityConfigurations

open Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
open Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders
open BackendDemo.Data.Models

type ProductionReportEntityTypeConfiguration =
    interface IEntityTypeConfiguration<ProductionReport> with

        override this.Configure(builder: EntityTypeBuilder<ProductionReport>) =
            builder.ToTable("ProductionReport") |> ignore
            //Todo
            ///builder.HasKey(fun r -> r.ProductionReportId) |> ignore
```

Here are the results of the suggestions below (thanks by the way!):

- 1 Try forcing an argument type

```
builder
    .HasOne(fun i -> i.ProductionReport) 
    .WithMany(fun (pr: ProductionReport) -> pr.CostItems)
```

[Result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/142PcimhD58wPZmY4Wsvd7vDQ7ZhfO93L)

- 2 Use the alternative Function syntax

```
builder
    .HasOne(<@ fun i -> i.ProductionReport @>) 
    .WithMany(<@ fun pr -> pr.CostItems @>)
```

[Result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17tjmEiIVnmNwSS_e8byWhy8XtgprusLF)

- 3 Use the <@ notation with specific type

```
builder
    .HasOne(<@ Func<ProductionReport,_> fun i -> i.ProductionReport @>) 
    .WithMany(<@ Func<CostItem,_> fun pr -> pr.CostItems @>)
```

[Result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YjT--rqIVkSEj9rGl1aoJrBg9nvumLs5)

- 4 Factorize the Expression solution from Nathan

```
static member toExpr (f:'a -> 'b) = 
    <@ Func<_,_> (f) @> 
    |> LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression 
    |> unbox<Expression<Func<'a, 'b>>>
```

[Factorization class](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OXBiXaCBA5iQFW-ueF6nDlXG_YZGEZEB)

[Result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NG6NvSUlEreNHiiX4uH0_7RI4gdzDwFJ)

- 5 Factorize the Expression with type notation suggested by Nathan

```
    static member toExpr<'a, 'b> (f:'a -> 'b) = 
        <@ Func<_,_> (f) @> 
        |> LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression 
        |> unbox<Expression<Func<'a, 'b>>>
```

[Result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q7zDLSoD5qvZt_Woh4ffszsfwJJjZHHp)

Comment: Can you provide a more complete sample so we can see the types of the builder and the DbContext / entities involved here?

Comment: I added the full code, there is a lot I have to fix. If you have also other improvements to suggestion I am open.

Comment: You can put a type annotation on the value inside the lambda expression: `.WithMany(fun (pr : ProductionReport) -> pr.CostItems)`. I find it a little odd that it should be necessary to do so, but I have next to no experience with EF, so who knows....

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the overloads for `HasOne` and `WithMany` that take in an `Expression` as input.  In C#, you use the "fat arrow" (`=>`) syntax for _both_ Expressions and Func/Action.  In F#, Expressions are treated separately with a different syntax.  I've not worked with these EF methods, but you might try the F# expression syntax: 
`.HasOne(<@ fun i -> i.ProductionReport @>).WithMany(<@ fun pr -> pr.CostItems @>)`
and see if that works.

Comment: @NathanWilson and TeaDrivenDev and  I tried your solutions and I updated my question at the bottom (last 2 points).

Comment: You can keep all classes that deal with Fluent API in C# as rewriting them in F# is always ugly in C# and call them from F#.

Comment: Ah, okay, I think we might be getting somewhere.  It says that `Expr<'b -> 'c>` is not compatible with `Expression<Func<_, _>>`.  In many cases, F# functions (`'b -> 'c`) are automatically converted to C# functions (`Func<'b, 'c>`) but not always.  It looks like in this case you might have to do the conversion yourself.  I would try 
`.HasOne(<@ Func<ProductionReport,_>(fun i -> i.ProductionReport) @>).WithMany(<@ Func<CostItem,_>(fun pr -> pr.CostItems) @>)`
Not sure if that's it, but that should at least make the func types compatible.

Comment: @abatishchev might be right in this case that either keeping the EF stuff in C# and referencing it from an F# project, or making some kind of wrapper around this EF code could be nice, because some of the F# syntax for working with these expressions is getting a little tedious...

Comment: @NathanWilson and abatishchev, I prefer to go with a pure F# solution for now because I want to avoid relying on C# as much as possible. I am also doing this as an exercise to learn how the F# syntax works, as ugly as it gets, because I want to use these cases as a stepping stone to learn the language in general. I updated my question to show the result of your fix. I also added back F# to the question title because I want this to be about F#, not C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it, but it took some digging to figure out how to work with the expressions.  I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23146624/revisions) post's *history* to see how to build a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`.  Here's what I have:

```
open System.Linq.Expressions
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers

...

let toProdRptExpr : Expression<Func<CostItem, ProductionReport>> =
  <@ Func<_, _> (fun (i:CostItem) -> i.ProductionReport) @>
  |> LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression 
  |> unbox<Expression<Func<CostItem, ProductionReport>>>

let toCostItemsExpr : Expression<Func<ProductionReport, seq<CostItem>>> = 
  <@ Func<_,_> (fun (pr:ProductionReport) -> pr.CostItems) @>
  |> LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression 
  |> unbox<Expression<Func<ProductionReport, seq<CostItem>>>>

let a = builder.HasOne(toProdRptExpr)
let b = a.WithMany(toCostItemsExpr)
```

that's a lot more verbose than it needs to be, but it helped me figure out how the types fit together.

**EDIT**

For brevity, you can create a function like

```
let toExpr (f:'a -> 'b) = 
  <@ Func<_,_> (f) @>
  |> LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression 
  |> unbox<Expression<Func<'a, 'b>>>
```

and then use it like

```
builder
  .HasOne(toExpr(fun (i:CostItem) -> i.ProductionReport))
  .WithMany(toExpr(fun (pr:ProductionReport) -> pr.CostItems))
```

But you have to be careful because it looks like CostItem and ProductionReport are *mutually referential* (see the discussion in comments below).  That means they need to be defined in the same file and use the `and` keyword (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7051721/8426314) example)

Comment: I was able to make it work. My code is big now, and I wonder: is there any way to wrap this into a function and takes the types and the fun as arguments? For Example: toExpr(CostItem, ProductionReport, (fun (i:CostItem) -> i.ProductionReport))

Comment: I bet you could do something like:
```
let toExpr (f:’a -> ‘b) =
  <@ Func<_,_> (f) @>
  |> LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression
  |> unbox<Expression<Func<‘a, ‘b>>>
```

Comment: But you should be able to call it with any regular F# function

Comment: I placed the code in my library and tried it. It worked if I use Has One only, but when I follow-up with WithMany it fails. I updated my question with the result.

Comment: Weird, it looks like `toExpr(fun (i:CostItem) -> i.ProductionReport)` is returning an `Expression<Func<CostItem, obj>>` instead of an `Expression<Func<CostItem, ProductionReport>>`.  Now you could probably try throwing additional type annotations in by putting `static member toExpr<'a,'b> (f:'a -> 'b) = ...` and `builder.HasOne(E.toExpr<CostItem, ProductionReport>(fun (i:CostItem) -> i.ProductionReport))` and hopefully that works, or at least gives us more info.

Comment: Alright, so I added the type annotations, and it seems to bring me back to the obj type problem for i.ProductReport. I updated the question with the error.

Comment: wow, we might have uncovered the deeper issue underlying some of this.  It seems like something is wrong with the definition of `CostItem` that its `.ProductionReport` field is just an `obj` and not a `ProductionReport`.  I mean we can fix the specific problem here by making a version of `toExpr` that takes in `(f: 'a -> obj)` instead of `(f: 'a -> 'b)`, but I think we need to figure out the underlying problem of why `CostItem.ProductionReport` is just `obj`...

Comment: Found it! It is in my CostItem class but I don't know how to fix it because Costitem type (or class) contains a ProductionReport and ProductionReport type (or class) contains a list of CostItem, and I can't have both orders in the solution explorer (move up, move down). So in the CostItem class, I am not able to force the ProductionReport member to a ProductionReport type with ```member val ProductionReport:ProductionReport = new ProductionReport() with get, set```. In my solution explorer, I put CostItem.fs above ProductionReport.fs.

Comment: Well, it looks like I'm at a roadblock here https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/removing-cyclic-dependencies/ . I think that this kind of object to object two-way dependency is not possible in F#.

Comment: I understand.  You _can_ do cyclic dependencies in F#, but the two have to be in the same file.  The second type gets declared with the `and` keyword _in place of_ the `type` keyword, and then the two can reference each other.  You're right though that cyclic dependencies between different files is disallowed

Comment: The article does not recommend it but I was able to get it to work by putting both types in one file using the ```and``` keyword. ```namespace BackendDemo.Data.Models
...
type CostItem() = 
    ...
    member val ProductionReport:ProductionReport = new ProductionReport() with get, set
 ...   
and ProductionReport() = 
    ...
    member val CostItems : List<CostItem> = [] with get, set```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191110/discussion-between-philippe-adib-and-nathan-wilson).